# mule cache managed object store with _defaultUserObjectStore not getting refreshed

Tags: mule, ehcache, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster

I am using mule cache managed object store with _defaultUserObjectStore and my data is not getting refreshed on the on-premises production server.

```
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy" >
        <managed-store storeName="_defaultUserObjectStore" entryTTL="600000" expirationInterval="600000"/>
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TTL is similar to you expirationInterval, that may cause the problem.
Do you actually had a look what those values mean?

Typically the expiration value will be short, it's the time it's checks for expired entries and if found deletes them.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/cache-scope#configobjstore